# How to safely run arbitrary code on a remote machine?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, heredoc

I would like to receive a shell command from a user, and run it as a Linux user with no real privileges.

Today I'm doing this: `sudo -u {username} 'sh' '-c' $'{user_command}'`

Is this safe?

Answer (score 1):

Manually escaping the `'` sounds fragile. I would put the command into a file and execute that file as a script. This avoids command injection by design.

Further note that even an unprivileged account will have read access to many files on the host system, like `/etc/passwd` or information from `/proc`. If they would run `ps` for example, they could see commands from other users.

Therefore I would recommend to run the command in a container. Install docker and run:

```
# let's say you stored the command in "user.sh" ...
docker run -v "${PWD}:/scripts" -it image_name bash /scripts/user.sh
```

---

Another thing which is relevant for security is that people could try to (a) DOS the host machine or (b) DOS other machines or attack them in a different way. For (a), make sure you put pretty strict resource constraints on the docker machine (mem, cpu, number of procs, etc...). For (b), disallow network access for the container.